# Search String Custom function algorithm

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I want to condition the string that I Inputted value ("ello") and variable("hello").

If It found in string("hello"), the return value should be "ello".
If not found, the return value should be -1.

But it returned "llll" 4 times because of condition *(strs[i] == arrayS[tempVal])*.

How can I get the correct answer as mentioned above?

```js
var stres = "hello";
var strs = [...stres];

function searchStr(s) {
  let arrayS = [...s];
  let tempVal = 0;
  let tempStr = [];
  while (tempVal < arrayS.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
      if (strs[i] == arrayS[tempVal]) {
        tempStr.push(arrayS[tempVal]);
      }
    }
    tempVal++;
  }

  return tempStr;
}

const res = searchStr("ello");
console.log('res', res)
```

Comment: what if the input is `Hlo`?

Comment: @decpk I added this after while loop. 
  const toString = tempStr.join("");

  "`if (toString !== s) {
    return [];
  } else {
    return tempStr;
  }`"

and then

"`const res = searchStr("Hlo");

if (res.length == 0) {
  return console.log("Not Found");
} else {
  const resS = res.join("");
  console.log("resS = ", resS);
}`"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to you, logic is correct just break the for a loop when the condition is fulfilled. Check below snippet and console output.

```js
var stres = "hello";
var strs = [...stres];

function searchStr(s) {
  let arrayS = [...s];
  let tempVal = 0;
  let tempStr = [];
  while (tempVal < arrayS.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
      if (strs[i] == arrayS[tempVal]) {
        tempStr.push(arrayS[tempVal]);
        break;
      }
    }
    tempVal++;
  }
  return tempStr;
}

const res = searchStr("ello");
const resS = res.join('');
console.log('res = ', res);
console.log('resS = ', resS);
```